Group by returning lists or values in spring jpa
I'm trying to do something really simple, but I somehow can't make it work without a native query.
Here is my entity:
public class A {
  private long id
  private String key
  private UUID value
}

In my repository, I have the following method:
@Query(value = """
        SELECT key as key,
            ARRAY_AGG(value) AS values
        FROM table_a
        WHERE key IN (:keys)
        GROUP BY key
""", nativeQuery = true)
List<MyProjection> getValuesByKeys(Collection<String> keys);

with
public interface MyProjection {
  String getKey();
  UUID[] getValues();
}

It works, and returns me a list of MyProjection objects, but I want to make it not a native query. I tried the following a various variations, but always have that error:
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: 'WITHIN GROUP' or 'OVER' clause is mandatory for ordered set aggregate function: array_agg

@Query(value = """
        SELECT new MyProjection(key, ARRAY_AGG(a.value))
        FROM A a
        WHERE a.key IN (:keys)
        GROUP BY a.key
""")
List<MyProjection> getValuesByKeys(Collection<String> keys);

I suppose array_agg is not the good method, but I can't find any info on what the correct call is.
Thanks in advance.

This one works for me
@Query(value = """
            SELECT new full.package.name.MyProjection(
                key,
                ARRAY_AGG(a.value)
                OVER (partition by a.key
                      order by a.id))
            FROM KeyValue a
            WHERE a.key IN (:keys)
    """)
List<MyProjection> getValuesByKeys(@Param("keys") Collection<String> keys);

I named my entity KeyValue for testing purposes.

It seems to work, but it returns me a byte[] for the list. Do you know if it is possible to make it  return a Collection or an UUID[] ?

If I remember correctly Hibernate have a problem with UUID, use String and parse it yourself.

I tried, but even a constructor using byte[] doesn't work, I have to use Object then cast it to byte[] then parse it, and even then, I have duplicated and incomplete results. I'll take another approach, probably group it in java.
